# Figuring out who changed the privilege?

Tags: windows, networking

Sorry if this is one of those really simple questions, but I am trying to figure out if there is any way I can see what user changed another users privileges.

I have a server running windows server 2008 r2, I currently only have two admins and for some reason the other day when I was looking I realized that there was an extra admin (someone who doesn't need it at all). I was wondering if there is a way I can see who (or even a time/date) that the user was changed. I have looked around and found this for 2003(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737542(v=ws.10).aspx), but I can't seem to find anything about it when it comes to 2008

(I am very new to this so once again sorry if this is a bad question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Event Viewer (Control Panel -> System and Maintenance -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer) and search for the category "Security". When the respective auditing policies are activated (which should be the default), you have the information there.

Comment: Object creation auditing is not enabled by default on any Windows Server OS.

Comment: Ok so I went to the place to view this policy and it says the policy setting is "not defined" which I am guessing means that I am out of luck on finding out who changed it/when it was changed ? or is there some other way of finding this out ?